# domainId from Google Chat API

Tags: google-hangouts

What is the `domainId` attached to a user defined in https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/User? The document says "Obfuscated domain information." What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

### The obfuscated domain id allows bots to group uses by team/domain

So while you will not be able to obtain the actual domain id, you will be able to know either users belong to the same domain or not (or which users belong to the same domain).

Comment: Sounds interesting. @ziganotschka, do you have any documents described that behaviour?

Comment: I could not find anything explictly saying it, but you can easily verify it through testing.

Comment: domainId is empty for external members. Is that something expected?